# Access denied on attempted DNS search order change

Tags: python, wmi

I'm trying to change my network adapter's prefered DNS in a script but I'm getting stonewalled by access restrictions:

```
import wmi

nic_configs = wmi.WMI().Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration(IPEnabled=True)
nic = nic_configs[0]
print(nic.SetDNSServerSearchOrder(["8.8.8.8"]))
```

This prints out (91, ) i.e access denied. Thoughts on getting around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to run this script with admin privilege -- for example, as covered at https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows , with `runas` or other alternatives mentioned there.